# how to define variable for HTML select

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-select

I have used PHP array for HTML select, then I put my codes in a template called data.php. I linked the data.php into index.php. so I want to define a variable for my HTML select `<select name="color">` in order that I can call this `<select name="color">` with its defined variable all across my theme.

```
$color=array(
     "R" => 'red',
     "Y" => 'yellow',
     "B" => 'blue', 
     "G" => 'green',
     "P" => 'purple',
     "O" => 'orange', 
     "B" => 'black',
     "G" => 'gray'
           );

<select name="color">
   <option value="">-----------------</option>
  <?php
  foreach($color as $key => $value):
  echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>'; //close your tags!!
  endforeach;
   ?>
</select>
```

Comment: use jquery/javascript to fetch option selected and then pass value to the php file via $.ajax if u wish to use jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, is this what you need ?

```
<?php
  $ColorOtions = "<option value=''>...</option>"; 
  foreach($color as $key => $value):
  $ColorOtions .= '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>'; //close your tags!!
  endforeach;
?>
```

Now you can call as `<select name="color">echo $ColorOtions;</select>`

Hope that helps..

Comment: Thanks a lot. it should be `<select name="color"><?php echo $ColorOtions; ?></select>` exactly. do you know how can I array fonts from Google Fonts like colors???